# search as you type in MS Access listboxes 

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Can any one guide me for the method/approch to implement searching-access-list-boxes-data-as-you-type-in-ms-access-forms with "mutiple items to select in list box"

Example to elaborate: I have a primary_skills list box field. Now I tried to choose multiple items ("DB2" and "SQL server" to select) where as I was able search first one  and selected the check box of db2 and later when I change search txt i get error pointing debug at me.refresh line of my code in "on change" event.
Error:Runtime error '3058': Index or Primary key can not contain a NULLvalue.

Note:current list box has 100+ items

Here is MY previous thread for more details:
[Searching Access List Boxes data as-you-type in MS access forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217945/searching-access-list-boxes-data-as-you-type-in-ms-access-forms)

Comment: Why not combine a list box to display the multiple items with a combobox, which has search as you type, to select the items?

Comment: I can not do this for my requirement. I want user to select different skills he aware so it could be of any combination of skills in my list box.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that as the user selects each skill from the combobox, it is highlighted in the listbox, or better, just added to an empty listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with the approach you outline in the link to the previous post is that it is very susceptible to performance problems and very frustrating for the user when they occur. It would be far better to take @Remou's suggestion and use a combox for dynamic searching.

Another approach would be to have two list boxes with add and delete buttons that move entries from the search list box to the selected list box in a similar fashion to the report wizard. then provide a textbox for the entry of a search string and a Find button that populates the search list box with matching entries.